# How I can add Account name from Subject of Email to Case

Tags: email2case

Here is a question regarding Email to Case.
In my org, we use Email to Case. The Subject of email-to-case is like : "Credit Hold : (ABCDEFGH ) : Sales Order : 1236589kmjl456"
Where ABCDEFGH = Account name.

On Case Page layout, we have a field = Account name.
Is there a way that This field can be auto filled from Subject by finding the string in ()? Because the Account name in subject is always in ( ).

I am an Admin, so I don't know much coding.

Comment: What tools are you comfortable using? What have you looked into so far? I assume you're aiming to populate the Account lookup, not just a text field with a name in it?

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct. I want a lookup field for Account name.
I am comfortable with, workflow rules and process builder (Proficient)  and flow builder (To Some Level).

Answer (score 1):

I think the only admin tool that will allow you to accomplish this is a product called  Lightning Flow, and there are a few Trailheads that can help you get your feet wet with this product.

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/business_process_automation

However, you may want to shy away from what you are asking about or at least think it through a little more. The reason I say this is because: to ensure you get the correct Account it would require that every account name in SFDC to be unique, and it would also require that the customer submitting the Web-to-Case to enter in the name of their account exactly as it appears in SFDC.

I don't think you can confidentially make sure you have found the correct account without those two things being true.

Some last warnings about Lightning Flow is that it's resource heavy, it may not be coding, but it is development so you should create your flow in a sandbox before implementing in Production, and lastly Lighting Flow does NOT have error handling or in other words, errors can be confusing and hard to diagnose for admin and user.

Comment: Yes, I understand your concern. The Account name is always unique across SFDC because this is coming from our ERP System. And its the ERP system, creating emails so account name will always be correct on Subject.

Thanks for investigating for me. I will try this using flow